# Type of usage/mood

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, verbs

jail house rock peaks.  (the *record* jail house rock peaks)

titantic sinks           (the *ship* the titanic)

Carter for president

film flops

Family flowers only please.

What do we call the mood for this usage where the context information is implied. Are they short sentences as they stand?

We commonly know 'ship' and 'record' so they omit ect.

Answer (score 2):

These read like newspaper headlines.

*Titanic* Sinks

Tottenham Wins Title

Sacco and Vanzetti Guilty

I would say, no, they do not stand as functional sentences.  They may grammatically be a sentence (subject: check; verb: check; predicate: check; etc) but they don't really work as functional sentences for me. Headlines.